# Linear model with heavy tails

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, heteroscedasticity, heavy-tailed

I am just approaching statistics and I find myself trying to fit different linear mixed models for my experimental data. My previous experience was mostly on lmer with binomial distributions, which are 'easily' fitted without too many worries.
Now I have to analyse a dataset in which I have 50 replicates which are grouped into 5 treatments. Each replicate consists in multiple observations over time, each performed every X seconds over a consistent period of time (60 obs. per group).
In my model I want to know whether my "Response" changes cause of my treatment and interactions between other predictors. I use my replicate as random factor, using the formula: (1 | ID).
Here's what my dataset looks like:  [EDITED]

```
dat1 = data.frame(
category = rep(x = 1, each=600),
ID = rep(rep(1:10,each=60)),
pred_1 = rnorm(n = 600,mean = 10,sd = 4),
pred_2 = rnorm(n = 600, mean = 5, sd = 5),
response = sample(c(0, 1), 600, replace = TRUE))

dat2 = data.frame(
category = rep(x = 2, each=600),
ID = rep(rep(1:10,each=60)),
pred_1 = rnorm(n = 600,mean = 10,sd = 4),
pred_2 = rnorm(n = 600, mean = 5, sd = 5),
response = sample(c(0, 10), 600, replace = TRUE))

dat3 = data.frame(
category = rep(x = 3, each=600),
ID = rep(rep(1:10,each=60)),
pred_1 = rnorm(n = 600,mean = 10,sd = 4),
pred_2 = rnorm(n = 600, mean = 5, sd = 5),
response = sample(c(5, 15), 600, replace = TRUE))


dat4 = data.frame(
category = rep(x = 4, each=600),
ID = rep(rep(1:10,each=60)),
pred_1 = rnorm(n = 600,mean = 10,sd = 4),
pred_2 = rnorm(n = 600, mean = 5, sd = 5),
response = sample(c(10, 30), 600, replace = TRUE))

dat5 = data.frame(
category = rep(x = 5, each=600),
ID = rep(rep(1:10,each=60)),
pred_1 = rnorm(n = 600,mean = 10,sd = 4),
pred_2 = rnorm(n = 600, mean = 5, sd = 5),
response = sample(c(15, 50), 600, replace = TRUE))

df <- rbind(dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4, dat5)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(category, ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    Time = seq(1, 60, by = 1)
  )
```

my linear model is:

```
mod <- lmer(Response ~ category + pred_1 * pred_2 + (1 | ID), df)
```

However, when I try to plot the residuals for model diagnosis I observe very heavy tails:
[image: qqplot1]
[image: qqplot2]

Things are slightly better when the first category is removed (which makes sense from the study perspective).
[image: qqplot3]
[image: qqplot4]

I tried to look here on the forum but I could not solve this issue, and not being able to evaluate how models fit I would like to hear some direct feedback. I think that a `glmmTMB` with `ziformula = .,` may be appropriate, but that is as far as my ideas go.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: It is worth mentioning that my `pred_1` variable is continuous, but the values are heavily clustered around very few values. `pred_2` is continuous and also kind of clustered around low values. `category` is a factor, but may be also interpreted as continuous as it represents the 'weigh' applied to the system. Here's some graphical representation:
[image]
[image]

After some suggestions, I tried to use a `log()` transformation but it only "inverted" the residual variance (so that the lower values had the highest variance).
A `sqrt()` transformation seems to partially help:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Data from the plot labelled "Homoskedasticity" don't look homoskedastic to me; in fact, results suggest clear heteroskedasticity.

Comment: Deal with nonlinearity (bias) and potential outliers/influential points first, then heteroscedasticity; worry about normality/tails **last**. Also, plotting sqrt(abs(standardized resids)) (and a trend line) works better than trying to detect heteroscedasticity by amplitude of the point cloud

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and for the edit. 
I was afraid that this was one of the issues, I am looking into heteroskedasticity just now.
@BenBolker can you please explain in more detail what you mean by dealing with nonlinearity? I was excluding the first category because is useless to my analyses and in my real dataset is only 0s.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; your sample data suggests a binary response. But your model and results assume normally distributed residuals. I agree with @BenBolker's earlier comment: We need more details involving the data generation process and/or more representative sample data.

Comment: Ops sorry! I could not understand what @BenBolker meant and now I got it. I copied the wrong df. Now it is correct!

Comment: Has anyone any help on my edited question?